# move SSL file from Cpanel to VPS

Tags: security-certificate

I have a Cpanel with valid SSL and now I wanna move SSL file from Cpanel to VPS. my VPS os is ubuntu and i use apache. how I can move SSL to VPS or create new SSL with old SSL file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not something I know about to help. We do have experts here, it is just a matter of time before someone jumps on board. Cheers!!

Comment: An X.509 certificate (what you call SSL) is just one file, with another one associated that holds the private key. So you just need to move/copy those files from one host to another. You need to find out where they are currently installed. Also you can not "create new SSL with old SSL file" in the sense that the certificate was issued to you by a Certificate Authority and you can not change anything in it, without making it invalid. If you need a new certificate you need to contact a certificate authority to issue a new one to you.